# Diferiantiating between onclick with nested elements

Tags: jquery

I have two elements that are within each other, both of them have .click() assigned to them, however when i click the child element(even tho it has higher z-index) the parent fires too. Here's an example:

```
<div class="element_add excluded"><div class="gear"></div></div>
```

jQuery looks like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".element_add", function() {
    alert("one");
});
$(document).on("click", ".element_add .gear", function() {
    alert("two");
});
```

Both of them fire even tho .gear has a higher z-index. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation()` (on the `event` object) to stop an event from bubbling to the parent:

```
$(document).on("click",".element_add .gear",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```